# how to exclude previous date from date picker

Tags: javascript, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker, bootstrap-datepicker

this is the javascript code. on the borrow date, it will show the previous date from today. how to diselect previous date from it?

```
        $("#date_borrow").datepicker({
            showAnim: 'drop',
            numberOfMonth: 1,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#date_return").datepicker("option", "minDate", dateToday);
            }
        });



        $("#date_return").datepicker({
            showAnim: 'drop',
            numberOfMonth: 1,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#date_borrow").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
            }

        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var dateToday = new Date();
        $("#date_borrow").datepicker({
            showAnim: 'drop',
            numberOfMonth: 1,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#date_return").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
            }
        });



        $("#date_return").datepicker({
            showAnim: 'drop',
            numberOfMonth: 1,
            dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
            onClose: function (selectedDate) {
                $("#date_borrow").datepicker("option", "minDate", dateToday);
            }

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add:

```
var dateToday = new Date();
```

and inside:

```
.datepicker({
...
minDate: dateToday,
```

In datepicker 1.9.0 from: https://uxsolutions.github.io/bootstrap-datepicker

```
startDate: new Date(),
```

Comment: I already update the codes as your suggestion but it exclude the day before today at the return date column

Comment: Sorry, I haven't understand what you mean, can you explain please?

Comment: this datepicker consist of two which are  `borrow_date` and `return_date`. what I wish is for the datepicker to exclude previous date than today is for the `borrow_date` but then it exclude the date at `return_date`